# Running multiple Regex once

Tags: python, regex

I have a very long file that I managed to parse using Python regular expression one value at a time, for example, here is the code that I'm using to print out all the values between the  `<h2>` tags:

```
import os
import re

def query():
    f = open('company.txt', 'r')    
    names = re.findall(r'<h2>(.*?)</h2>', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
    for name in names:
        print name

if __name__=="__main__":
    query()
```

and I repeat the same thing to print out the `area_code` as well. But this time, I just replace the *pattern* in the findall function to print the area code. This means I'm having to run the code twice.

My question is, is there a way to simply run the two queries at the same time and printing the results in one line separated by a pipe (|)?
like so: `Planner | B21`

Below is the short sample file I'm trying to parse.

```
    <h2>Planner</h2>
    area_place = 'City of Angels';
    area_code = 'B21';
    period = 'Summer';
    ... more content
   <h2>Executive</h2>

    area_place = 'London';
    area_code = 'D33';
    period = 'Winter';
    ...more content
```

Comment: If you are dealing with HTML I'd suggest to use an HTML parser to parse the `<h2>` tags and use the regex to get the `area_code` on the data of the element that should contain that.

Comment: Thanks for that, I currently don't have trouble parsing, it's just that I want to parse and print all the return values in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me with your test data in Python 2.7, give it a try:

```
import os
import re

def query():
    f = open('company.txt', 'r')    
    names = re.findall(r"<h2>(.+?)</h2>.*?area_code = '(.+?)'", f.read(), re.DOTALL)
    for name in names:
        print name[0] + " | " + name[1]

if __name__=="__main__":
    query()
```

Basically, I'm just incorporating both queries into one, and then specifying the capture group numerically.  You may want to rename "names" since it makes less sense the way I'm doing it.

Alternatively, if you'd like to keep your existing queries and you can assume that they will all be the same length, you could do something like this:

```
names = re.findall(your names regex)
area_codes = re.findall(your area code regex)

for i in range(len(names)):  //very dangerous, if there's one failed match many entries may be mismatched!
    print names[i] + " | " + area_codes[i]
```

However, I would not recommend this approach unless you're extremely confident in the regularity of your data.

Comment: Thanks @lmortenson, your tip above has done the trick. I can now print the results - each on it's own line. Much appreciated :)